# jquery repopulate table form fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple html table that starts off with two rows. Each row contains 2 form fields. User's can add additional rows to the table as follows:

```
$('a#addRow').click(function() {
    $('#jTable tr:last').after('<tr>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="foo[]" value="" id="foo[]" /></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="bar[]" value="" id="bar[]" /></td></tr>');
    return false;
});
```

This works fine.

However, if there is an error detected after the form is posted, then I need to recreate the table with the correct number of rows. At the moment, after posting, the table defaults back to the two starting rows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do this server side.

Controller:

```
$data['rows'] = count($_POST('foo'));
```

View

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="foo[]" value=<?php echo $foo[$i]; ?> id="foo[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar[]" value=<?php echo $bar[$i]; ?> id="bar[]" /></td>
    </tr>       
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to port posting of data from standard html-post to AJAX requests. That will ensure that the site is not reloaded when the form is posted -> your table will stay as it is. See [JQuery Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

On submitting form you can store the number of lines in table.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // Cool stuff here
    // ...
    localStorage.setItem('nbLinesinTable', $('table > tr').length);
    // or add input to form
}
```

The k_wave solution's is also reliable.